# How to separate between IP and port using vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, proxy, listbox

How to Separat between IP and port using vb.net ?
I have listbox that contains proxy list like 192.168.1.2:80
and I want to use it in this code 
Proxy.SetProxy(ip, Convert.ToInt16(port))
and I cant change the code 
you can look here for the full idea and hole code
http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/42674-Setting-IE-proxy-from-vb-net-applications.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Main()
    Dim parts() As String = "192.168.1.2:80".Split(":")
    Dim ip As String = parts(0)
    Dim port As String = parts(1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Don't split the string twice! That's unnecessary use of resources. Split it once and store the resulting array in a variable instead and use that.

Comment: I considered that, but to me it cluttered the example.

Comment: I think what you have now is much more readable (and easier to understand) than what you had before. :)